# How to Truncate Table using CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, truncate

I want to truncate my Database Table, with CakePHP Model, I have used `$this->Model->deleteAll` code for the same, and it works fine.

Now, What i want is, next time whenever my new records are inserting, it should start `ID` with 1 only, which does not work with `deleteAll` function, so Is there any default CakePHP Syntax to make table **Truncate** ?

Let me know !

Comment: can achieve by: `$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE TABLE table_name');`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**NOTE: This answer is valid only up to CakePHP 1.3. I haven't used this on the never versions so I've no idea whether it works.**

`deleteAll` only deletes the data, it does not truncate the table.

You'll need to call the `query()` method.

```
$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE TABLE table_name_in_mysql;')
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1027/query

Comment: Only one warning -- it`s mysql-specific and not in all DBMS we could have truncate. [It was officially introduced in the SQL:2008 standard.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL))

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->Model->query('TRUNCATE table tablename;')`

Comment: @trante, I try like your way, but query can't execute. What should I do?

Comment: @DoNhuVy This answer is quite a few years old and I haven't worked with Cake in a long time. I'm sorry but someone who's worked on the new CakePHP will need to weigh in.

Comment: It does work on Mysql with CakePHP 2.X "tablename" should be the name on mysql table, not the alias, nor the Model name.

Answer (score 3):

@JohnP's doesn't take into account the table's prefix as configured in [database.php](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#database-configuration). Here's a slightly more robust approach.

The [DboSource](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html) object attached to each model already has a [fullTableName()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html#_fullTableName) method that does exactly what we need.

First, [create](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models) `Model/AppModel.php` if it doesn't already exist, and add this method to it:

```
/**
 * fullTableName
 *
 * Provides access to the Model's DataSource's ::fullTableName() method.
 * Returns the fully quoted and prefixed table name for the current Model.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param boolean $quote Whether you want the table name quoted.
 * @param boolean $schema Whether you want the schema name included.
 * @return string  Full quoted table name.
 */
public function fullTableName($quote = true, $schema = true) {
    $datasource = $this->GetDataSource();
    return $datasource->fullTableName($this, $quote, $schema);
}
```

With this, you can get the full table name, including the prefix, for **any** Model in your Cake app:

`$this->Model->fullTableName();`

We can do better though. Next, add this method to AppModel too:

```
/**
 * truncate
 *
 * Truncates ALL RECORDS from the Model it is called from! VERY DANGEROUS!
 * Depends on the ::fullTableName() method to concatenate the configured
 * table prefix and table name together and quote the whole bit properly.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function truncate() {
    $fullName = $this->fullTableName();
    $q = 'TRUNCATE TABLE %s';
    return $this->query(sprintf($q, $fullName));
}
```

Now you can (easily, so be careful!) truncate any Model in your app like so:

`$this->Model->truncate();`

And if you ever need to adjust the SQL query to match a different DataSource, you can do so in a central place in your app. You can also easily override the `truncate()` method in specific models if they use a different DataSource with a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A database driver agnostic solution for CakePHP 3:

Create an `AppTable.php`, and make all your tables extend this one.

Add this function to it:

```
public function truncate()
{
    $truncateCommands = $this->schema()->truncateSql($this->connection());
    foreach ($truncateCommands as $truncateCommand) {
        $this->connection()->query($truncateCommand);
    }
}
```

Then simply call `$table->truncate();` and it should truncate the table regardless of which database driver you use.